# Windows Error: exception: access violation reading 0x00000160

Tags: python, windows, exception, access-violation

I am very new to Python and am running a program to send and receive ethernet packages with a Nexys3 board. I open the pointer to the ethernet device in the init method, store it in a global variable, and then access it in both send and receive methods. In both methods, I get the error:

WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000160

I've done a lot of research and discovered that this Windows error means that the restart operation failed, but I don't know what this means or how to go about fixing it.

I'm not able to post my code, so I'm not looking for a quick and easy fix. I am just wondering if anyone has ever come across this error before and what it might mean or indicate about my code. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a "post your generic description of a problem and we'll brainstorm with you" site, and without the code that's causing the exception that's what this will become. It's for specific, concise programming (code) and programming tools related questions. Google will give you your "take a guess at what might be wrong" ideas, though. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) can give you some information on what types of questions are proper to ask here. Staying on-topic is part of how SO stays a useful resource for programmers. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like your pointer may be [dangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). The 0x160 is not a Windows error code, it is a memory address.

Comment: A snippet of the code you're using would help this question greatly. Maybe you could add that to the question then flag to re-open. Thanks.